# Share folder on external Drive over Network with SAMBA

Tags: linux, samba, fstab

My external drive is either not mounted at boot or not accessible (samba) on the network. Solving either one problem would suffice to achieve what I want.

I have an external Drive connected to my Debian machine.
There is a folder on it, that contains pictures.

My intention is to make this folder available on the network so I can access this directory on my Laptop.

Here are the steps I have taken, but not achieved what I want:

1. Get the UUID of the drive. Differing from the guides I have viewed online, my UUID is quite different, it looks like this. DACA165CCA1634EB as opposed to the long number with dashes.
2. I edited `/etc/fstab` to have this partition automatically mounted at boot time, using this line:

   ```
   UUID=DACA165CCA1634EB "/home/phil/Pictures/nfo" auto defaults 0 0
   ```

   however, the folder is not mounted at this location at boot. I can mount it at this mountpoint manually by using the commands
   `umount` first and then `mount` again.
3. I edited `/etc/samba/smb.conf` to have the path `/home/phil/Pictures/nfo` shared, which works.

   HOWEVER, I thought I can share the mount point that is automatically chosen by the system at boot, which is located at `/media` like all removeable media. For this I need to comment-out the `fstab` line.
   I added a samba-share block like this:

   ```
   [Fotos,Bilder]
   comment = Bilder, Fotos
   public = yes
   writeable = yes
   browsable = yes
   path = "/media/phil/extern_drive/Bilder. Backup"
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777
   guest ok = yes
   only guest = no
   ```

   But trying to access it on the network does not grant me access. Not even with my log-in credentials.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: if i type `sudo mount -a` I get this error: tfs-3g-mount: bad mount point "/home/phil/Pictures/nfo": No such file or directory - But the directory exists!

Comment: Is your Linux set up to use encrypted home directories? If so, then `/home/phil` may be actually mounted only while you're logged in (as your login password is needed as a key to unlock the encryption of your home directory).

Comment: Your home directory is only accessible by you. The ondisk permissions supersede the SMB permissions. Mount the external drive elsewhere. Also, is selinux enabled?

Comment: no, home directory is not encrypted. also, IF I mount the external drive manually in `home/phil` it IS accessible through samba. It is NOT accessible through samba if the mountpoint is on `/media`